# Calculation of Poincare dual to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I would like to go about finding an explicit representative of the Poincare dual to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in $\mathbb{CP^{n+1}}$, I am following Bott & Tu and would like an explicit form to be wedged with itself and integrated to give the Chern numbers for $\mathbb{CP^{n+1}}$. 
The reason I am having difficulties is that, although I have managed to calculate the Poincare dual for simple things like circles in the torus, I can't think of how to go about choosing the right coordinates to work in. Should I for example consider $\mathbb{CP}^n =\{[z_0,\ldots,z_n,0]\}$ and then look for the Poincare dual to this submanifold in standard coordinates over the patches $\{U_i=\{[z_0,\ldots,z_{n+1}]\colon z_i\neq0\}\colon i=1,\ldots,n\}$ before patching these together with a partition of unity? The problem with this idea seems to me that I won't end up with a global form, it won't be defined at the point $[0,\ldots,0,1]$. Moreover, given any copy of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ in $\mathbb{CP^{n+1}}$, there doesn't seem to be any way to cover $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$ with $\mathbb{CP}^n$ contained in every patch.

Comment: By looking at cohomology rings you can see that you want the Poincare Dual form to represent the (positively oriented) generator of $H_2(\Bbb{CP}^{n+1};\Bbb Z)$. By explicit calculation you can show that the Fubini-Study form satisfies this, as long as you pick the appropriate scaling. Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help much, how does one calculate the Fubini study form (I'm not sure what it is), and how does one show that this is the Poincar\'e dual? I understand that the cohomology ring is generated by the Chern classes, but I would like to do an explicit calculation to find a form $\eta_{\mathbb{CP^n}}$ satisfying
$ \int_{\mathbb{CP}^n}i^*\omega = \int_{\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}}\eta_{\mathbb{CP}^n}\wedge\omega \quad \forall \omega $

Comment: The point is that the Kähler form $\eta=\dfrac1{2\pi i}\partial\bar\partial\log \|z\|^2$ (if I haven't messed up a constant) gives the generator of $H^2(\Bbb CP^n,\Bbb Z)$. By naturality, you check this by integrating over a (standard) $\Bbb CP^1$ (say $z_2=\dots=z_n=0$). It then follows that since integrating $\eta$ over $\Bbb CP^1$ computes the intersection number of $\Bbb CP^1$ with a hyperplane $\Bbb CP^{n-1}$, $\eta$ must be the Poincaré dual of $\Bbb CP^{n-1}$.